# Integration of $e^{\cos x}\cos x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Could you please help me to solve this integration problem? I could not find an exact symbolic expression for it.
$$\int {{e^{\cos x}}} \cos xdx$$

Comment: Hint : Integration by parts.

Comment: I do not see any obvious trick for doing it.

Comment: @PranavMarathe no because it is not easy finding the antiderivative for $e^{\cos x}$

Comment: In the case that anyone is interested, Wolfram Alpha does not yield a closed form expression for this integral.

Comment: There's no analytical way to express its antiderivative http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ecos+x+cos+x+dx

Comment: @VarunIyer Oh right. Sorry, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: Are you actually trying to integrate that over some nice interval?

Comment: The only method, that I can think of, that would yield anything tangable would be to use the Taylor series expansion for $e^{\cos x}$ and then swap the integral and series, since $e^{\cos x} > 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Gahawar Writing out a Taylor series could get horribly complex.

Comment: @PranavMarathe It undoubtedly would, but the OP may have to resort to such if he is indeed looking for a primitive.

Answer (score 6):

The indefinite integral knows no closed form expression, as can be proven by using either [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). However, if we add $0$ and $\dfrac\pi2$ as the two limits of integration, then the result is $\dfrac\pi2\cdot\Big[I_1(1)+L_{-1}(1)\Big]$, where *I* and *L* are the [Bessel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) and [Struve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) functions, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Lucian, there is no closed form expression. As said by Lucian and TylerHG, there are quite nice expressions for the integral $$\begin{align}
F_k&=\int_0^{k \frac{\pi}{2}}e^{\cos( x)}\cos(x)dx\\F_1&=\frac{1}{2} \pi  ({L}_{-1}(1)+I_1(1))\\F_2&=\pi  I_1(1)\\F_3&=\frac{1}{2} \pi  (3 I_1(1)-{L}_{-1}(1))\\F_4&=2 \pi  I_1(1)\\F_5&=\frac{1}{2} \pi  ({L}_{-1}(1)+5 I_1(1))\\F_6&=3 \pi  I_1(1)\\F_7&=\frac{1}{2} \pi  (7 I_1(1)-{L}_{-1}(1))\\ F_8&=4 \pi  I_1(1) \\F_9&=\frac{1}{2} \pi  ({L}_{-1}(1)+9 I_1(1))\end{align}$$ where obvious patterns can be noticed.

Comment: Minor nitpick: you have $F_n$ together with $$\int_0^{k\frac \pi 2}$$... These are intended to be the same variable $n,k$, correct?

Comment: @abiessu. Thanks; it is $F_k$.

Answer (score 1):

As Lucian said there is no closed form expression for this undefinite integral, but the modified Bessel function of the first kind can be defined with a definite integral of the form (for integer $n$):

$$I_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}e^{x\cos u}\cos(nu)du$$